# Is it acceptable to use ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads to throttle the amount of work a service performs?

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, azure, threadpool

I have a service which polls a queue very quickly to check for more 'work' which needs to be done. There is always more more work in the queue than a single worker can handle. I want to make sure a single worker doesn't grab too much work when the service is already at max capacity.

Let say my worker grabs 10 messages from the queue every N(ms) and uses the Parallel Library to process each message in parallel on different threads. The work itself is very IO heavy. Many SQL Server queries and even Azure Table storage (http requests) are made for a single unit of work.

Is using the **TheadPool.GetAvailableThreads()** the proper way to throttle how much work the service is allowed to grab?

I see that I have access to available *WorkerThreads* and *CompletionPortThreads*. For an IO heavy process, is it more appropriate to look at how many CompletionPortThreads are available? I believe 1000 is the number made available per process regardless of cpu count.

*Update* - Might be important to know that the queue I'm working with is an Azure Queue. So, each request to check for messages is made as an async http request which returns with the next 10 messages. (and costs money)

Comment: Why would a worker grab more than one job at a time? Use the TPL producer/consumer queue classes and just let it do its stuff...

Comment: I don't think the number of items requested is relevant. Unless you are suggesting that I don't process the message async and instead ask for 1 message and process it completely before asking for another. Unforunately this has a 'cost' to it since every request made for a message costs money. That is why I was trying to grab 10 at a time and process them in parallel.

Comment: @Vyrotek: I was suggesting that you ask the TPL to manage how many threads are used (using Parallel.ForEach or whatever), but that you grab one at a time. You hadn't made it clear that each request for a message cost money.

Comment: Slow I/O heavy threads are the worst kind of threadpool thread to have.  It takes a while for the TP scheduler to release enough waiting threads to get 'enough' of them running.  It only adds them at a rate of one per 1/2 second.  Consider increasing MinThreads or using regular Threads.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Multi-message queue reads are important when balancing performance and cost in Windows Azure. Each queue read is a Storage Transaction (and it runs $0.01 per 10K transactions). An ISV my team is working with will be accessing approx. 1B storage objects monthly. Looking at all queue, blob and table accesses (which are costing more than one transaction per object access), transaction cost starts to show up on the monthly invoice. When reading from an Azure Queue, you can specify the number of items to read at once, resulting in a single-transaction HTTP GET.

Comment: ...although... I guess one could argue that, if you're generating a billion object reads monthly, you're probably making enough $$$ to make transaction cost seem irrelevant. :)

Comment: Last I checked, you can get up to 32 messages from a Windows Azure queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to keep an internal counter of how many message are currently being processed. I used Interlocked.Increment/Decrement to manage the counter in a thread-safe manner.

I would have used the Semaphore class since each message is tied to its own Thread but wasn't able to due to the async nature of the queue poller and the code which spawned the threads.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using IO completion ports is a good way to work out how much to grab.

I assume that the ideal situation is where you run out of work *just* as the next set arrives, so you've never got more backlog than you can reasonably handle.

Why not keep track of how long it takes to process a job and how long it takes to fetch jobs, and adjust the amount of work fetched each time based on that, with suitable minimum/maximum values to stop things going crazy if you have a few really cheap or really expensive jobs?

You'll also want to work out a reasonable optimum degree of parallelization - it's not clear to me whether it's *really* IO-heavy, or whether it's just "asynchronous request heavy", i.e. you spend a lot of time just waiting for the responses to complicated queries which in themselves are cheap for the resources of your service.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working virtually the same problem in the same environment. I ended up giving each WorkerRole an internal work queue, implemented as a BlockingCollection<>. There's a single thread that monitors that queue - when the number of items gets low it requests more items from the Azure queue. It always requests the maximum number of items, 32, to cut down costs. It also has automatic backoff in the event that the queue is empty.

Then I have a set of worker threads that I started myself. They sit in a loop, pulling items off the internal work queue. The number of worker threads is my main way to optimize the load, so I've got that set up as an option in the .cscfg file. I'm currently running 35 threads/worker, but that number will depend on your situation.

I tried using TPL to manage the work, but I found it more difficult to manage the load. Sometimes TPL would under-parallelize and the machine would be bored, other times it would over-parallelize and the Azure queue message visibility would expire while the item was still being worked.

This may not be the optimal solution, but it seems to be working OK for me.

Comment: Fantastic response! This is exactly the sort of thing we have been exploring as well. Very helpful experience, thanks.

Comment: May I also ask why you went with a BlockingCollection instead of other things such Queue.Synchornized?

Comment: Basically for the TryTake() method. I'm using CancellationToken's to handle shutdown, and TryTake() will respect those. Also, BlockingCollection<> is supposed to have better multi-threaded performance due to some stuff they did with thread local storage.  

In practice, I don't know if it's appreciably faster than a synchronized queue, but BlockingCollection<> seems to be working well for me. 

I should note that I initialize the BlockingCollection<> with a ConcurrentQueue(), so I still get the queueing behavior.